# In a chatbot conversation using dialogflow, Is there a way to make the bot speak first?

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, dialogflow-es

Is it possible to format a conversation so that the bot initiates conversation using dialogflow in a web demo integration?

The objective is to say something like “Hi, I’m a bot, I can do x” to establish that it’s a chatbot rather than a human.

Can anyone suggest any idea for this?

Comment: Have you try to use Welcome events in a intent?

Comment: this https://dialogflow.com/docs/events#default_welcome_intent ?

Comment: Sir @RogersonNazário how should i use welcome event in a intent so that bot respond first?

Answer (score 3):

You can set a welcome intent, then send a `/query` request containing an `event` parameter. Set the `event` parameter to `WELCOME` and your chatbot will respond with whatever conversation opening you set.

More info here: https://dialogflow.com/docs/events

Comment: when i created a welcome intent i which "welcome" event is made i get error saying:"Intent with empty contexts and events '[WELCOME]' already exists". i checked through all intents still its showing exists.Previously i deleted a welcome intent is this the reason behind that error?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, maybe you should post it as a separate question. Have you tried making a new agent and using the default welcome intent?

Comment: sir i am unable to achieve the stated output by any of the solution given. Is there any other way?

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, but you can send a "Hello" message to Dialogflow without prompting the user. Then you just continue the conversation normally from there. I used to do that before they added events.

Comment: Sir how to do that?

Comment: Here's the documentation on sending queries to Dialogflow: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent

If that doesn't help, I recommend making a new question about how to send a query to the Dialogflow REST API.

Comment: I haven't found this answer really useful, the explanation is too vague. How do you send a `/query` request? Do you mean using the v2.beta API? Does it work for the web integration, or only for other integrations (facebook, google assistant, etc.) ? I thought about using webhook fulfillment but it's not triggered without user input. I do have a WELCOME event in the `Default Welcome Intent` but it doesn't trigger by itself AFAIK. Definitely don't with the Web integration.

Comment: @Vadorequest Sorry, I don't have any experience with the Facebook, Google Assistant, etc. integrations so I can't tell you about those, but the answer works when interfacing via the web API. It was written before the v2 API was released, and I haven't really got any experience with the v2 API so I can't update the answer myself. Feel free to edit the question.

Comment: @Vadorequest The WELCOME event doesn't trigger by itself. To trigger it, you need to send a request to Dialogflow (`/query` on the old API) with the `event` parameter set to `WELCOME`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using something other than the API for interacting with your Dialogflow agent (Slack, Facebook Messenger, etc.) you will need to add an appropriate event under "intents" in your console (such as the "Facebook Welcome" event).
2. For interacting with your Dialogflow agent via the API, see below.

In the [API interaction quickstart documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/api), Dialogflow gives you the SessionClient's detectIntent method for sharing messages with your bot.

Each language has a different solution. But on an abstract level, you want to change the request object that you send to Dialogflow to include a "Welcome" event (no input message required), as Omegastick described.

For example, in Node.js, your request object would look like this:

```
// The text query request.
        const request = {
            session: sessionPath,
            queryInput: {
                event: {
                    name: "Welcome",
                    languageCode: languageCode
                }
            },
        };
```

This assumes you have an appropriate intent set up in your Dialogflow console to handle Welcome events. One is provided by default that you can observe.

You can also add contexts, so that your agent gives a different greeting message based on some condition.